# 2.3.5 Authorize.net issue

Tags: authorize.net, magento2.3.5-p1

Trying to complete my 2.3.5 site and need to add my Authorize.net configuration. I see no place to accept credit cards under the "Payment Methods". We are setup with Auhtorize.net and also use it on our 1.9 site. However on 2.3.5 it is "Deprecated". How else can we utilize Authorize.net and configure it. After all this has no way of being able to accept credit cards

Answer (score 0):

You can install the official Authorize.net plugin from the Magento Marketplace website.  It may not work in Magento 2.4 (not tested) but will work in Magento 2.3.5

https://marketplace.magento.com/authorizenet-magento-module-authorizenet.html